# Action over selected items on a collection

Tags: java, apache, isis

I'm developing an application using Apache Isis and I didn’t find any examples on how to present a collection (list of items), allow the user to select only some of them, and to execute an Action which will be applied only to the **SELECTED** ones.

Is it possible to be done? Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is, in fact, supported: you need to use @Action(associateWith=...), see [1].

For example, suppose we have a "removeItems(…)" action:

```
public class Order {

    @Collection
    SortedSet<OrderItem> getItems() { ... }

    ...

    @Action(associateWith="items", associateWithSequence="2")
    public Order removeItems(SortedSet<OrderItem> items) { ... }
}
```

The Wicket viewer will then render the "items" collection with checkboxes, and any selected items will be used as the pre-selected set of items if the action is invoked

HTH
Dan

[1] http://isis.apache.org/guides/rgant/rgant.html#_rgant-Action_associateWith